# Floyd–Warshall algorithm in GAMS

Tags: gams-math

I want implement the Floyd–Warshall algorithm in GAMS . i need to find  shortest paths in a weighted graph with positive weight .

Below is   the algorithm in C++

```
 void Floyd_Warshal(int graph[MAX][MAX], int D[MAX][MAX], int P[MAX][MAX], int numberOfNodes){
      for(int i = 0 ; i < numberOfNodes ; i++)
        for(int j = 0 ; j < numberOfNodes ; j++){
          D[i][j] = graph[i][j];
          P[i][j] = -1;
        }
      for(int k = 0 ; k < numberOfNodes ; k++)
        for(int i = 0 ; i < numberOfNodes ; i++)
          for(int j = 0 ; j < numberOfNodes ; j++)
            if(D[i][j] > D[i][k] + D[k][j]){
              D[i][j] = D[i][k] + D[k][j];
              P[i][j] = k;
            }
      }
}
```

`D` is adjacent matrix of original graph, and `p` is path . in fact `p` is the result.

Can I change this code to GAMS code , I mean , can we have   Floyd–Warshall algorithm in GAMS,according to this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look the following address

https://www.gams.com/latest/gamslib_ml/libhtml/gamslib_sroutex.html

It's similar  to Floyd–Warshall algorithm .